# Any way to resolve forward declaration in a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I have a template class defined as such:

```
template <typename T> void ProxyNoOp(T *) {}
template <typename T> void ProxyDelete(T * ptrT) {delete ptrT;}

template <typename T, typename C, void (* Release)(T *) = ProxyNoOp<T>  >
class Proxy
{
public:
    class Container : public std::list<T *>
    {
    public:
        Container() {}
        ~Container() {clear();}

        void clear()
        {
            iterator clsEnd = end();
            for (iterator clsCurrent = begin(); clsCurrent != clsEnd; ++clsCurrent)
            {
                T * ptrT = *clsCurrent;
                static_cast<Proxy *>(ptrT)->m_ptrContainer = NULL;
                Release(ptrT);
            }   
        }
    };

private:
    iterator m_clsPosition;
    C *      m_ptrContainer;

public:
    Proxy() : m_ptrContainer(NULL) {}
    ~Proxy()
    {
        if ( m_ptrContainer != NULL )
        {
            Container * ptrContainer = static_cast<Container *>(m_ptrContainer);
            static_cast<std::list<T *> >(ptrContainer)->erase(m_clsPosition);
        }
    }

    C * GetContainer() const {return m_ptrContainer;}
};
```

A lot of the code has been removed or changed for the sake of brevity.  The idea of the data structure is that not only does a container maintain references to contained elements, but the contained elements maintain a reference to the container PLUS their position in the container, making removal quick (constant time) and automatic (called in the destructor)

A problem with this approach can be demonstrated by this code:

```
#include "proxy.h" // the above template class

class Child;
class Parent : public Proxy<Child, Parent>::Container {};
class Child : public Proxy<Child, Parent> {};
```

When compiling `Parent`, the definition of `Proxy<Child, Parent>::Container` causes an error at this line: `static_cast<Proxy *>(ptrT)->m_ptrContainer = NULL;` - at the point in the compilation, `Child` has not been defined, only declared.  If I change the  declaration order of `Parent` and `Child` to be this:

```
#include "proxy.h"

class Parent;
class Child : public Proxy<Child, Parent> {};
class Parent : public Proxy<Child, Parent>::Container {};
```

the definition of `Proxy<Child, Parent>` causes an error at this line: `Container * ptrContainer = static_cast<Container *>(m_ptrContainer);`, the reason being the same as before - at that point in the compilation, `Parent` is not fully defined.

Is there any way I can get around this and still use templates?  Is there a standard data structure in STL, BOOST, etc. that accomplishes this?

**EDIT:**

The code will not compile as-is, I should have been clearer about that (to quote myself from above: *A lot of the code has been removed or changed for the sake of brevity.*).  It doesn't actually use `std::list<T *>`, but a custom doubly linked that is effectively the same.  I didn't want to post a ton of ancillary code when only asking about this one issue.

I wasn't asking for critique on the data structure itself (although I am fine to hear it), but for those wondering why it was created here are a couple examples:

A game engine has models and instances of those models, such as a war game where there is one tank model and any number of tanks created from it.  The classes could be written as such:

```
class Instance;
class Model : public Proxy<Model, Instance, ProxyDelete<Instance> >::Container {...};
class Instance : public Proxy<Model, Instance, ProxyDelete<Instance> > {...};
```

When a model is deleted, all instances made from that model should also be deleted (hence the `ProxyDelete<Instance>` template parameter) since it doesn't make sense for an instance to exist without the model it was made from.

Suppose your graphical user interface (GUI) renderer keeps track of all visible elements (buttons, frames, etc.) so it knows what to render, but text is rendered differently since it is a different call to the graphics API:

```
class GuiTextElement;
class GuiRenderer : public Proxy<GuiRenderer, GuiTextElement, ProxyNoOp<GuiTextElement> >::Container {...};
class GuiTextElement : public Proxy<GuiRenderer, GuiTextElement, ProxyNoOp<GuiTextElement> > {...};
```

---

The less astute will say "why don't you simply add `std::list<Instance *>` as a member of the `Model` and `std::list<GuiTextElement *>` as a member of `GuiRenderer`?".  Here are a few reasons:

1. Elements that are "owned" by their containers are not automatically deleted when the container is destroyed (yes, I am aware of `boost::ptr_list`).
2. There is no way, without adding another class member, to refer to the container using a contained element.  For example, to get a `Model` from an `Instance`.
3. If you did add a class member to accomplish #2, you would also need to update it when elements are removed from their containers.
4. For the speed fanatics - if contained elements don't maintain an iterator to their position in the container, before that element can be removed the container must first be searched for it.

Comment: if elements maintain thier position, I think that would make removal _slower_ not faster.

Comment: Now that I've read the question, nothing here makes sense.  And everything I see here terrifies me.

Comment: However, the general solution to this sort of problem is to design `Proxy` so it _doesn't_ require `Parent` or `Child` (pick one) to be defined.

Comment: If elements do not maintain their position, the list has to be searched for that particular element before it can be removed, no?  The tradeoff is 8 extra bytes per `Proxy` instance (16 bytes on a 64 bit system), which seems minimal.

Comment: What doesn't make sense and why is it terrifying?

Comment: If they _do_ maintain their position, the list has to be _modified_ to update the posisition after an insert or remove.  So it's 8 extra bytes, and you do linear time _writes_ instead of linear time _reads_.

Comment: This implementation uses a linked list, and from the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list): "Addition, removal, and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted."

What other _writes_ could there be when modifying the list?

Comment: If each node has an index of it's position, all indexes after the removed would need updating.  Unless it's just an iterator?  In which case I don't understand what you're doing, because `std::list` already does this.

Comment: This is particularly bad. You should strive to reduce coupling, not increase. An object is useful without any information about container(s) where it might be inserted. If you are interested in both X and X's position in some container, use a piece of data that has both X and X's position in some container, i.e. an iterator. If you need to add the container itself, use a pair (ptr to container,  iterator). There's no need to make X aware of any of this.

Comment: Your compile error is not traceable. You forgot `#include<list>` and there is no definition of `iterator`.

Comment: Instead of spending multiple lines trying to explain the missing pieces and how it's supposed to work, could you adapt the example to something that doesn't require those missing pieces, so others have code to read and compile instead of having to imagine it?

Comment: I've made some trivial modifications to get your code to compile far enough to repro your problem, [here](http://pastebin.com/j452zHrp). And, having done that, it compiles with no warnings or errors, with clang 4.2, g++ 4.6, and g++-4.2-apple, both C++11 and C++98 when appropriate, with no additional flags. So, have my trivial modifications changed something relevant?

Comment: You are correct, I should have prepared a compilable version of the code.  I'm unclear as to your code example; it reproduces the problem but compiles without warnings/errors?  The two seem mutually exclusive since the problem is that my code won't compile.  Either way, thanks for taking the time to do it.

Comment: @jorgander: That's the point: It does _not_ reproduce the problem. I attempted to get past the other errors that previous commenters have pointed out, so I could reach your problem—but it's not there. This is a little hard to explain in a comment, so I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the code you've shown us exhibits the problem you're asking about.

I made minimal changes to get past the earlier compiler errors, so I could get to the point where I could reproduce your problem. But, having done so, your problem does not exist.

Here are my changes:

- Add `#include <list>`.
- Replace each instance of `iterator` with `typename Container::iterator`
- Make `Container` inherit from `list` publicly instead of privately, so I get access to its `iterator` type.

You can try adding them one by one to see what errors each one solves—none of them have anything to do with your problem. Or you can [download the code](http://pastebin.com/j452zHrp) and compile it yourself.

I compiled this with a three different compilers, clang-4.2, g++-4.6, and g++-4.2-apple; in both C++11 and C++98 modes where appropriate; with -Wall enabled. In all cases, it compiled without any errors or warnings.

Also I don't see how the referenced line could have the error you described. It doesn't matter whether `T` or `C` are incomplete, because all you do is:

- `static_cast` a `T *` to a `Proxy *`, which only requires having `T` declared, not defined.
- Access a member of a `Proxy`, which does not depend in any way on type `T`.
- Set a `C *` to NULL, which only requires having `C` declared, not defined.

The *previous* line depends on calling `operator *` on an `iterator`, and that's apparently a custom class of your that might be dependent on `T` or `C` in some way, but that couldn't possibly cause an error on the next line.

So, there are a few possibilities:

- The error is not the error your described, nor is it on the line you described, and the problem is in either the `iterator` class or the `list` class that you didn't show us.
- The code you've shown us is so different from your real code that it no longer has even a trace of the part that causes a problem.
- My trivial changes aren't as trivial as I thought and somehow fixed your problem.